# Linux CPU affinity for all system processes

Tags: c, linux, affinity

Is there a way to set all system processes other than my own process' threads to their own CPU without manually setting each pid.

I am using C on Fedora and would like to set this on program start not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cgroups` (control groups) are an [effective way of partitioning system resources](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Resource_Management_Guide/Starting_a_Process.html) (even more than just CPUs).  Also, another effective way of getting exclusive CPU access for a process is to leverage the scheduler -- give it higher priority than anything else.

If those aren't what you want, and you've decided that you really, really want to control CPU affinity using single-bit masks, you can walk the process tree starting with init (try using `system` with [this example of how to use `ps` at the shell](https://superuser.com/questions/286219/unix-list-children-processes-for-a-given-pid)).